# How do I find an element by its id in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is my code:

I have used the find element by id RESULT_RadioButton-7_0, but I am getting the following error:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/home/real/Desktop/Selenium_with_python/SeleniumProjects/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver")

driver.get("https://fs2.formsite.com/meherpavan/form2/index.html?153770259640")

radiostatus = driver.find_element(By.ID, "RESULT_RadioButton-7_0").click()
```

My error is this:

> elementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element  is not clickable at point (40, 567). Other element would receive the click: <label for="RESULT_RadioButton-7_0">...</label> (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.70)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the page link you provided, it looks like your locator strategy is correct here. If you are getting an error—most likely `NoSuchElementException`, I am assuming it might have something to do with waiting for the page to load before attempting to find the element. Let's use the `ExpectedConditions` class to wait on the element to exist before locating it:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
# Add the above references to your .py file

# Wait on the element to exist, and store its reference in radiostatus
radiostatus = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "RESULT_RadioButton-7_0")))

# Click the element
#radiostatus.click()

# Click intercepted workaround: JavaScript click
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", radiostatus)
```

This will tick the radio button next to "Male" on the form.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the below answer which will help you to click on the *"Male"* radio button from your link.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://fs2.formsite.com/meherpavan/form2/index.html?153770259640')

# Clicking on the "Male" checkbox button

maleRadioButton = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "RESULT_RadioButton-7_0")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(maleRadioButton).click().perform()
```

Comment: Why are you using actions class to perform a regular click? The user did not say anything about a clicking issue, they just wanted to locate the element.

Comment: I have tried your code but I am facing below error to avoid that I have provided another solution: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <input type="radio" name="RESULT_RadioButton-7" class="multiple_choice" id="RESULT_RadioButton-7_0" value="Radio-0"> is not clickable at point (355, 606). Other element would receive the click: <label for="RESULT_RadioButton-7_0">...</label>
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)

Comment: It’s worth clarifying that in the answer you posted, so other users who see your answer will understand why you use action chains class.

Comment: will take care next time,i can see now you have updated your code to handle ElementClickIntercepted exception thanks

Answer (score -1):

Unless you need to wait on the element (which doesn't seem necessary), you should be able to do the following:

```
element_to_click_or_whatever = driver.find_element_by_id('RESULT_RadioButton-7_0')
```

If you look at the source for [`find_element_by_id`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py#L162), it calls `find_element` with `By.ID` as an argument:

```
def find_element_by_id(self, id_):
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
```

IMO: `find_element_by_id` reads better, and it's one less package to import.

I don't think your issue is finding the element; there's an `ElementClickInterceptedException` when trying to click on the element.  For example, the radio button is located, but (strangely) Selenium doesn't think it's displayed.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://fs2.formsite.com/meherpavan/form2/index.html?153770259640")

radiostatus = driver.find_element_by_id('RESULT_RadioButton-7_0')

if radiostatus:
    print('found')
    # Found
    print(radiostatus.is_displayed())
    # False
```

Comment: If `find_element_by_id` is the same as using `find_element(By.ID)`, then how is this answer any different than what the original asked posted in their sample?